# Merging a merge request using Gitlab API commands

Tags: api, groovy, merge, gitlab, commit

I'm trying to merge a merge request using the gitlab api and following is what I'm doing using groovy, but I keep hitting errors, I'm pretty new to this so any help is greatly appreciated!

```
def MRUrl = "https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v4/projects/project_name/merge_requests/113/merge"

def post = new URL(MRUrl).openConnection();
post.setRequestMethod("PUT")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.setRequestProperty("Private-Token", "${Key}")
post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

def responseCode = post.getResponseCode();

Error / exception:
No such property: message for class: gitLab
```

The gitlab API call is from the following documentation.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr

Comment: There is no `message`.  Most likely here: `post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Comment: I feel kinda sheepish, but thanks! That was it

Answer (score 0):

cfrick has provided the answer to this issue