# Creating Gitlab branch from JIRA

Tags: gitlab, jira

I have recently started using Gitlab and integrated with Jira. Both Gitlab and Jira server are self hosted internally in my corporate environment.

I have come across a requirement where I want to create a branch in Gitlab for a project/issue directly from the JIRA issue.

Is it possible to do it? If yes then how? Is there any plugin required for that?

I have gone through some documentation but I couldn't find anything similar so if anyone has any idea please let me know.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html

Answer (score 5):

This is now supported, with [GitLab 14.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/08/22/gitlab-14-2-released/#create-a-gitlab-branch-from-a-jira-issue) (August 2021), in certain condition (Jira Cloud):

> ### Create a GitLab branch from a Jira issue
>
> Users of the [GitLab.com for Jira Cloud](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221011/gitlab-com-for-jira-cloud) application can now create GitLab branches directly from a Jira issue’s [development panel](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/view-development-information-for-an-issue/).
>
> This enables developers to begin work on issues without having to switch tools and lose context.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_2/jira_dev_panel_jira_setup_3.png -- Create a GitLab branch from a Jira issue]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/connect-app.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/2647).

Comment: Confirmed - this is now available for GitLab

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible using the embedded Gitlab-Jira integration.

In jira, I suppose you have a workflow with statuses and transition. You need to configure a [post function](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/configure-advanced-issue-workflows/#Advancedworkflowconfiguration-postfunctions) on your transition to call Gitlab API from your jira using groovy [script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53314866/2653911).