# Gitlab + Jira intergration with automatic issue transition on merge/pull requests for multiple branches

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, jira

I am trying to set up automatic transition of Jira issues to their respective statuses on Jira with Gitlab triggers.

My current workflow is as follows:

1. Task issued in Jira
2. Create and name a branch with Jira issue ID (ex: JIRA-324)
3. Push new branch to repo
4. Merge request JIRA-324 to development branch
5. Test on development server
6. Merge request development branch to master branch
7. Deploy code

As there could be multiple branches merged to develop branch (Eg. Jira issues: JIRA-324, JIRA-523, JIRA-264, etc) before merging development branch to master branch, the problem arises when development branch gets merged to master. Jira doesn't know what issues are included development branch. If I manually enter the branch names into the development to master merge request description or title then Jira can pick that up and transition the correct issues.

So, my questions would be:

1. Is it possible to some how populate the merge request from development to master to include every commit message (as the commit message always contains the Jira issue ID) OR
2. Tell Jira to look into the "Commit" section of Gitlab to determine what issues are inside this merge request?

Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68898924/6309, which can avoid you having to push a branch.

Comment: Thanks but my IDE (PhpStorm) integrates with Jira and automatically pulls Jira tasks then creates branches based on the ID when I start working on that task in the IDE. As for my question, I ended up having to write my own custom web-hooks to append the task ID's onto the Dev to Master merge request when sending it to Jira's API.

Comment: OK. Is there any chance you could publish parts of your custom hook as an answer to your own question? (for others to benefit from it)